# IIS 8.5 HTTP Error 404.0, 0x80070002

Tags: php, mysql, iis, iis-8.5

I tried installing IIS 8.5, MySQL and PHP last night on my new VPS and failed dramatically.

Unlike many other HTTP Error 404.0, 0x80070002 errors, my site can run PHP pages but it fails to find the page if it attempts to connect to a MySQL database.

I've searched all night looking for a solution to my problem, and since haven't found said solution.

Here is the error page itself:

[image: Error]

Thank you very much in advance,
Arron

**EDIT**
Index.PHP Code:

```
<?php 
define('IN_INDEX', 1);

require_once 'global.php';

$core->handleCall($engine->secure($_GET['url']));

$template->write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">');

$template->write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');

$template->write('<head>');

$template->write('<title>');

$template->write('Chrome: Index');

$template->write('</title>');

$template->css->get();

$template->js->get();

$template->write('</head>');

$template->write('<body>');

$template->html->get($engine->secure($_GET['url']));

$template->write('</body>');

$template->write('</html>');
$template->outputTPL();
?>
```

Commenting out global.php on this page will allow the page to load.

Global.PHP:

```
<?php

// Special Functions

function filter($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($var)));
}

if(!defined('IN_INDEX')) { die('Sorry, you cannot access this file.'); }
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) { $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] =  $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']; }
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

define('A', 'app/');
define('I', 'interfaces/');
define('M', 'management/');
define('T', 'tpl/');


//REVOLUTION

use Revolution as Rev;


//INTERFACES

    require_once A . I . 'interface.core.php';

    require_once A . I . 'interface.engine.php';

    require_once A . I . 'interface.users.php';

    require_once A . I . 'interface.template.php';

    //TPL

        require_once A . T . I . 'interface.forms.php';

        //HTML

            require_once A . T . I . 'interface.html.php';

        //CSS

            require_once A . T . I . 'interface.css.php';

        //JS

            require_once A . T . I . 'interface.js.php';


//CLASSES

    //app

    require_once A . 'class.core.php';

    require_once A . 'class.engine.php';

    require_once A . 'class.users.php';

    require_once A . 'class.template.php';

    //MANAGEMENT

        require_once A . M . 'config.php';

        require_once A . M . 'recaptchalib.php';

    //TPL

        require_once A . T . 'class.forms.php';

        //HTML

            require_once A . T . 'class.html.php';

        //CSS

            require_once A . T . 'class.css.php';

        //JS

            require_once A . T . 'class.js.php'; 


//OBJ

$core = new Rev\core();

$engine = new Rev\engine(); 

$users = new Rev\users();

$template = new Rev\template();

$template->form = new Rev\forms();

$template->html = new Rev\html();

$template->css = new Rev\css();

$template->js = new Rev\js();

//START 

session_start();

$engine->Initiate();

$template->Initiate();

?>
```

(Removing config.php in the Global.PHP file will allow the page to load)

Config.PHP:

```
error_reporting(0);
if(!defined('IN_INDEX')) { die('Sorry, you cannot access this file.'); }.

/*
*
*   MySQL management
*
*/

$_CONFIG['mysql']['connection_type'] = 'pconnect'; //Type of connection.

$_CONFIG['mysql']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //MySQL host

$_CONFIG['mysql']['username'] = 'root'; //MySQL username

$_CONFIG['mysql']['password'] = 'PASSWORD'; //MySQL password

$_CONFIG['mysql']['database'] = 'chrome_db'; //MySQL database

$_CONFIG['mysql']['port'] = '3306'; //MySQL's port

?>
```

Comment: So if you comment out the DB connection this works? Can you add the code?

Comment: @chris85 Yes, if I comment out the DB connection the code works but comes up with a PHP error because I'm using the connection to get data from  database - I shall add the code now.  Edit: Which code? The database connection or the index page itself?

Comment: The page that is causing this.

Comment: @chris85 I believe I have now added all the code.